# How can I use parameters in a bash script as subject text to grep?

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I have  a simple bash script, which receives a file with subject text, and processes line by line.
If the line begins with certain characters - then run block of compound commands. 
I am trying to use grep to test the lines for patterns (but would accept other suggestions).

#### file: matcher.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for i in "$@"
do
    if grep "^M" $i   # I want grep to "assume" $i was a file
                      # and test if the pattern "^M" is present 

    then
        echo "This line started with an M: "$i 
        # command 1
        # command 2
        # etc
    fi
done
```

#### Subject_text.txt

```
D       bar
M       shell_test.sh
M       another_file
```

Then run script with

```
cat subject_text.txt | xargs --delimiter="\n" ./matcher.sh
```

How can I get grep to treat each iteration `$i` through the parameter list 
as if `$i` were a file?

Comment: So you want to run `matcher.sh` against every second value in `subject_text.txt`?

Comment: Each line in `subject_text.sh` should be a single parameter to `matcher.sh` which is why I've delimited by the `\n` .

Comment: It isn't very clear what you want. Do you want to match the first field character in the file in the second field?

Comment: no, just read the subject text - line by line - and test if the pattern is present - if so - run a block of commands, is that more clear?

Comment: No not really. `Subject_text.txt` has two fields, passing that into your script will split it into (for the first line) `D`, and `bar`, so will try and grep inside the file `D`, which I'm assuming won't exist . I honestly can't work out what you are trying to do...

Comment: no - it doesnt get split - the `--delimiter="\n"` tell `xargs`  to treat each string within new line characters as one argument

Comment: It does get split, your script has nothing to do with xargs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the file `Subject_text.txt` in a loop and feed `matcher.sh` with the name of the file to check:

```
while IFS= read -r _ file_name
do
   ./matcher.sh "$file_name"
done < "Subject_text.txt"
```

However, now that I see, you are using `matcher.sh` over every line. Note that calling a script with every single line as parameter is a bit overkilling.

What about looping over the file normally and performing the `grep`?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

file=$1

while IFS= read -r line
do
    if grep "^M" <<< "$line"   # I want grep to "assume" $i was a file
                           # and test if the pattern "^M" is present 

    then
        echo "This line started with an M: $i"
        # command 1
        # command 2
        # etc
    fi
done < "$file"
```

Comment: the reason for the grep command is less about text manipulation and more the fact it will return `exit status 0`  - that way triggering the `if .... then ` to run

Comment: @user4668401 not sure what you mean here. Do you need the exit status? Note that `awk` con provide it. Update your question indicating more clearly what is your intention, so I can try to adjust my answer.

Comment: yes - I meant the  result of the `grep` command will be `0`  - thereby causing the `if ... then` to run

Comment: @user4668401 OK, now I understand. There is no need to do something complicated here, just loop through the file normally as I indicate in my update : )

Comment: Im getting error: >  grep: D       bar: No such file or directory - same problem I had - grep is expecting to see a file - not a variable.

Comment: @user4668401 are you reading the data with the `while` block I mention in the beginning? If so, debug it by saying `echo "$file_name"` to make sure it fetches the file name there. Note `_` is to read the first data (D, M...) and depending on the format you may need to change the `IFS` if fields are tab-separated, for example.

Comment: yes your looping setup is fine - that does what its supposed to - I'm suspecting the problem is still with the fact we are trying to put a variable "$line" where grep expects a file. Ive also been trying to `cat $line | grep "^M" no luck on that either

Comment: I just used your script with `if echo "$line" | grep "^M"` and it seems to be working!

Comment: @user4668401 oh, stupid me. Since you are grepping a line, it is like `grep "regex" <<< "$line"`. Updated!

Comment: yes!  `grep "regex" <<< "$line"` - Thats what I was hoping for - a command that existed that I didn't know about - thanks !